# Angular 12 Usar pipe desde componente

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

Hola tengo problemas para usar desde un componente en Angular 12 (desde la vista si funciona).

Es un pipe que instale, aunque ya he probado con varios y pasa lo mismo.

En concreto es este https://www.npmjs.com/package/@josee9988/filter-pipe-ngx

Hago esto:

```
app.module.ts

..

import { FilterModule } from '@josee9988/filter-pipe-ngx';
..

imports: [FilterModule],
..

providers: [FilterModule],
..
```

Y en comp1.component.ts

```
import { FilterModule } from '@josee9988/filter-pipe-ngx';

..

constructor(private FilterModule_: FilterModule) { }

..

funcion1 () {
   this.v1 = this.FilterModule_.transform(this.v2, "gfg", v3);
}

..
```

Y me dice que "error TS2339: Property 'transform' does not exist on type 'FilterModule'"

Y no me deja ni levantar el ng serve.

Gracias de Antemano.

Un Saludo.

Comment: Buenas compañero, si es un Modulo, no se puede usar así... En la web del componente te indica bien cómo usarlo. Igual, ¿entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es filtrarlo desde el .TS? Si es así, lo que debes hacer es modificar la variable con la que filtras, como hace en uno de los ejemplos con la variable searchText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar el `pipe` directamente en el componente debes crear una instacia:

```
export class AppComponent  {
    
      constructor() {
        let filterPipe = new FilterPipe()
        let a = [{
          a: 'demo'
        },
        {
          a: 'abcd'
        }]
        let b = filterPipe.transform(a, 'demo')
    
        console.log(b);
    
      }
    }
```